# Do we say enthusiasm 'for' or 'about'?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, prepositions

Do we say enthusiasm 'for' or 'about'? I saw both of them used in different texts.

Comment: Here's a related question, although it's not quite the same: [What preposition is used after “enthusiastic”: “for” or “about”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360784)

Comment: The previous question, which sumelic links to, did not reach a conclusion and achieve an accepted answer. It would be good if this question managed to do so.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE!  We appreciate your participation.  If you have not already done so, please take [our tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).  Also, allow me to introduce you to our sister site, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), which is especially useful for people learning English as a second language.

Answer (score 2):

It would be *enthusiasm* **for**

or *enthusiastic* **about**

Comment: Hello Sarah; can you cite a source to back up this answer so people will know that they can rely on it? For example, the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enthusiasm+about%2C+enthusiasm+for%2C+enthusiastic+about%2C+enthusiastic+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centhusiasm%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Centhusiasm%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Centhusiastic%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Centhusiastic%20for%3B%2Cc0) seems to support your answer. I don't know if you would like to use that; something else could also work.

Comment: (+1) Upvote since the Ngram supports.